# what does "sk" stand for?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I really face some difficulty reading names of some methods since there is no appendix for their abbreviations at Apple, for the method: SKPaymentQueue, what does SK stand for ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stands for `StoreKit`. Note the header you used to get at that class, `StoreKit.h`.